# Polarization to define trivial and non trivial topological phases?

Tags: topological-insulators, topological-phase

Polarization is well defined for particle hole symmetry systems, so can we use polarization to identify topological phases? for example polarization can have possible value
$$P=0 \quad or \quad1/2$$
so can we define topolgical invariant in terms of polarization?
$$v=\frac{1}{\pi} \oint dk A(k)$$

Comment: Yes. This is how the invariant is defined in particle-hole symmetric insulators in 1+1d.

Comment: @MengCheng can we use the above topological invariant in terms of polarization to differentiate between trivial and non-trivial phases of 1+1d topological superconductor.